# How to match two columns from different dataframes returning True/False using regex?

Tags: python, pandas

There are two dataframes DF1 and DF2, both containing a column called ID

How do i check if each ID row in DF1 is in column ID in DF2, returning True/False in DF1?

Example of ID is 56AB209876.

I have tried using isin but the results are all FALSE. I am wondering how should i do this in regex?

Comment: you tried `df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])` ?

Comment: Yes. but it seems because of the combination of letters and numbers, unable to use isin. Trying to use regex but im not sure how i should do it.

Comment: For Pandas questions, it is useful to add a small example of your dataframes (doesn't have to be your actual data, just the relevant columns/similar data, enough so other users can understand the problem easier

Answer (score 0):

`Series.isin()` should work. The mix of alpha and numeric characters should not make a difference.

```
d1 = {'ID': ['12AB34','34CD45','67EF89','99XY88']}
d2 = {'ID': ['43PP87','34CD45','91GH29','99XY88','12AB34']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

print(df1)

       ID
0  12AB34
1  34CD45
2  67EF89
3  99XY88


print(df2)

       ID
0  43PP87
1  34CD45
2  91GH29
3  99XY88
4  12AB34

df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
```

Comment: I had actually amended DF1[‘ID’]. Previously the data has whitespaces e.g. 21 AB2346. In order to match with DF2[‘ID’], i used regex: re.sub(r”\s+”,””,str(x) for x in DF1[‘ID’]. When i view the data now, the spacing is gone but it seems the the numbers before the spacing are strings and after the spacing they are still objects. Because of this i cant match it.

Comment: @gnation If you gave us some samples of the ID column in df1 and df2 we could help you figure this out.